# is it possible in blackberry to capture image automatic

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am new in blackberry. i create Application now my requirement is when camera is invoke automatic a picture is capture.Is it possible in blackberry.
i am using this code every thing work but not capture picture automatic please suggest what i change on my code it's work on my Application.

```
 public class Test extends MainScreen  implements FileSystemJournalListener {
    long _lastUSN;
    ButtonField btnTakePhoto;
    String capturedImgPath = "";
    VideoControl videoControl;
    Timer objTimer;
    Player player;


    public Test()
    {
        super();
        btnTakePhoto    =   new ButtonField("Take Picture",ButtonField.VCENTER|ButtonField.BOTTOM);
        btnTakePhoto.setChangeListener(TakePictureListener);
        HorizontalFieldManager hfm=new HorizontalFieldManager();    
        hfm.add(btnTakePhoto);
        add(hfm);

        System.out.println("Inside Construct");
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().addFileSystemJournalListener(this);
        _lastUSN = FileSystemJournal.getNextUSN();
        this.setTitle("Camera Class");
    }



    FieldChangeListener TakePictureListener = new FieldChangeListener(){

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            System.out.println("Inside fieldChanged");
            doTakePicture();
        }
    };
    public void doTakePicture(){
        try
        {

            System.out.println("Inside doTakePicture");
          Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_CAMERA,new CameraArguments());
          player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");
          player.realize();

          videoControl = (VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl");
          player.start();
          if(videoControl!=null)
          {
              Field videoField = (Field) videoControl.initDisplayMode (VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");


              videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
              videoControl.setVisible(true);
               add(videoField);
//            System.out.println("videoControl=="+videoControl);
//            String imagetype = "encoding=jpeg&width=1024&height=768&quality=fine";    
//           
//            byte[] snapshot = videoControl.getSnapshot(imagetype);
//            Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(snapshot, 0, snapshot.length, 5);
//            System.out.println("snapshot=="+snapshot);
//            System.out.println("image=="+image);
//            BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField();
//            bitmapField.setBitmap(image);
//            this.add(bitmapField);
//            if(videoField != null)
//              {
//                  add(videoField);
//                 
//              }

          }



        }



    catch(Exception ex)
     {
        System.out.println(ex);

     }
    }

    public boolean invokeAction(int action)
    {
        System.out.println("Action=="+action);
    boolean handled = super.invokeAction(action); 
    //handled=true;
    System.out.println("handled=="+handled);
    System.out.println("Inside Invoke Camera");

    if(!handled)
    {    
        System.out.println("Inside First If Blog"); 
        if(action == ACTION_INVOKE)
        {   
            System.out.println("Inside Second If Blog");
           try
            {    
                System.out.println("If Blog of invoke Action");


                System.out.println("videoControl11=="+videoControl);
              String imagetype = "encoding=jpeg&width=1024&height=768&quality=fine";    
              byte[] snapshot = videoControl.getSnapshot(imagetype);
              Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(snapshot, 0, snapshot.length, 5);
              System.out.println("snapshot=="+snapshot);
              System.out.println("image=="+image);
              BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField();
              bitmapField.setBitmap(image);
              this.add(bitmapField);


           }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Dialog.alert(e.toString());
            }
     } 


    }
    return handled;                
}  



    public void fileJournalChanged() 
    {
        System.out.println("Inside fileJournalChanged");
        long nextUSN = FileSystemJournal.getNextUSN();
        String msg = null;
        String path = null;
        for (long lookUSN = nextUSN - 1; lookUSN >= _lastUSN && msg == null; --lookUSN) 
        {
            FileSystemJournalEntry entry = FileSystemJournal.getEntry(lookUSN);

            if (entry == null) 
            { 
                break;
            }

             path = entry.getPath();
             System.out.println("Path=="+path);

            if (path != null)               
            {
             if (path.endsWith("png") || path.endsWith("jpg") || path.endsWith("bmp") || path.endsWith("gif") ){    
                switch (entry.getEvent()) 
                {


                    case FileSystemJournalEntry.FILE_ADDED:
                        System.out.println("Inside FILE_ADDED");
                        msg = "File was added.";
                        break;

                    case FileSystemJournalEntry.FILE_DELETED:
                        System.out.println("Inside FILE_DELETED");
                        msg = "File was deleted.";
                        break;
                }
             } 
            }
        }
        _lastUSN = nextUSN;

        if ( msg != null ) 
        {
            Dialog.alert(msg);
            capturedImgPath =   path;
            closeCamera();
        }
    }
   private void closeCamera()
    {
        int menuOrder =6;
        System.out.println("Inside Close Camera");
        EventInjector.invokeEvent(new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN, (char)Keypad.KEY_MENU, KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD, 0));
        EventInjector.invokeEvent(new EventInjector.TrackwheelEvent(EventInjector.TrackwheelEvent.THUMB_ROLL_DOWN, menuOrder, KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD));
        EventInjector.invokeEvent(new EventInjector.TrackwheelEvent(EventInjector.TrackwheelEvent.THUMB_CLICK, 1, KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD));
        Dialog.alert("The captured Image path is "+capturedImgPath);
   }



}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a legacy approach to take pictures. This is why you shouldn't use it:

- Because you are exiting your application to call an external application (the camera app).
- Because you don't have control over the camera settings.
- Because the FileJournalListener code that you posted, which is the code RIM published in its tutorial, gives problems on some OSes and simulators (events arriving in a different order or not arriving at all, multiple events on image save, etc).
- Because there is no way to close the camera app and you have to resort to the hacky key injection method.

So now, for OSes > 4.6, you can use MMAPI to take snapshot inside your app. This is the recommended method and you should not use the one you posted unless you are programming for legacy OSes. Check [this tutorial](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1089414/How_To_-_Take_a_snapshot_using_the_built-in_camera_of_a_BlackBerry_smartphone.html?nodeid=1443849&vernum=0). Also, from 5.0 onwards you can use AMMAPI to control some camera settings. [Not all controls are implemented](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Advanced-Multimedia-Supplement-API-What-s-Supported/ta-p/770659), but most basic ones (zoom, focus, flash, etc) are supported in the latest OSes. Check the <strike>CameraDemo</strike> VideoRecordingDemo sample included in the latest BlackBerry JDE.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but I will note that your second point can actually be an *advantage* of the legacy approach.  I've written this app before, and the customer specifically wanted all normal Camera settings, and look-and-feel, to apply ... and I can totally see the end user liking that. I agree that the key injection method was a royal pain, but I got it working, and to the end user, it looked just like a new screen being pushed and popped.

Comment: Yes, point #2 is not a problem for many users. But for some applications it is (i.e: barcode scanning, document scanning, where you need specific zoom/flash settings; or when you need to limit the size of the picture files in order to send them over the internet in devices lacking 3G).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, this will automatically take picture.

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;
import javax.microedition.media.Player;
import javax.microedition.media.control.VideoControl;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class ImageCaptureDemo extends UiApplication
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ImageCaptureDemo app = new ImageCaptureDemo();
    app.enterEventDispatcher();
}

public ImageCaptureDemo()
{
    pushScreen(new ImageCaptureDemoScreen());
}   

class ImageCaptureDemoScreen extends MainScreen
{   
    Timer timer ;
    Player _p;
    VideoControl _videoControl;    

    public ImageCaptureDemoScreen()
    {
        try 
        {
            _p = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?encoding=jpeg&width=320&height=240");
            _p.realize();
            _videoControl = (VideoControl) _p.getControl("VideoControl");

            if (_videoControl != null)
            {
                Field videoField = (Field) _videoControl.initDisplayMode (VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");
                _videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
                _videoControl.setVisible(true);
                _p.start();

                /*EnhancedFocusControl efc = (EnhancedFocusControl)p.getControl("net.rim.device.api.amms.control.camera.EnhancedFocusControl");
                efc.startAutoFocus();*/

                if(videoField != null)
                {
                    add(videoField);
                }
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Dialog.alert(e.toString());
        }


        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new CountDown(), 3000);


    }

    public class CountDown extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
         DismissThread dThread = new DismissThread();
         invokeLater(dThread);
      }
   }
 public void dismiss() {
      timer.cancel();
     invokeAction(ACTION_INVOKE);
    _videoControl.setVisible(false);

   }
   public class DismissThread implements Runnable {
          public void run() {
             dismiss();
          }
       }



    protected boolean invokeAction(int action)
    {
        boolean handled = super.invokeAction(action); 

        if(!handled)
        {
            if(action == ACTION_INVOKE)
            {   
                try
                {                      
                    byte[] rawImage = _videoControl.getSnapshot(null);  


                    FileConnection conn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpeg", Connector.READ_WRITE);
                    conn.create();
                    OutputStream out = conn.openOutputStream();
                    out.write(rawImage);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    conn.close();

                    /*

                    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(rawImage, 0, rawImage.length, 5);
                    BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField();
                    bitmapField.setBitmap(image);
                    this.add(bitmapField);
              */

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Dialog.alert(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }           
        return handled;                
    }  
}   
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Replay but it's not working on device.u test it on ur device.

Comment: i tested on 8520 device.i set the time as 1000. @user1337883

Comment: but friend it's not work on my device. without click trackball on ur device image is capture and save it on ur sd card i think no.

Comment: i am also tested on blackberry curve model 8520  but not working realy.

Comment: this code will automatically take picture and display it. it will not save the image on SD card. if you want to save it on SD card, you have to explain it to the question. your question doesnt contain any word about saving image on SD card.@user1337883

Comment: @user1337883 turn off the sound in your device.